# Tabla PDF a JTable

Tags: java, pdf, jtable

He investigado y hay mucha información respecto a como convertir la información de una tabla contenida en un JTable(JAVA) a PDF,pero en sí no he visto que se haga esto a la inversa ,es decir de una tabla contenida en archivo PDF a un JTABLE ¿Es posible realizar esto con alguna API o componente?¿Han intentado?

Comment: Todo es posible. Agrega que has intentado tú para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Yo he utilizado Apache PDFBox https://pdfbox.apache.org/ con esta librería puedes leer el pdf obtener la tabla y recorrerla.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la fuente de datos que alimenta el PDF,  si pero si no la tienes es muy difícil. El PDF fue creado para no modificarse, eso es lo que le da portabilidad y de ahí su nombre Formato de Documento Portable. El hecho de que no pueda modificarse dificulta su manipulación, aun así existen APIs con las que se logran leer ciertos metadatos y contenido, pero son inestables ya que los metadatos varían en función de la tecnología con la que fue hecho. En pocas palabras necesitas acceso al origen de la información que alimenta el PDF. Si basas tu aplicación en tener que leer datos de un PDF,  te puedo decir casi con total seguridad que tu aplicación no esta planteada correctamente. Verifica con quien te proporciona el PDF si puede darte acceso a un webservice, base de datos, csv, etc. donde este el origen de datos de ese PDF.  Tambien nos ayudaría saber que tipo de PDF es, me refiero a que podría ser un CFDI u otro formato público  y desconoces donde esta el origen.